# vfs_rename on linux filesystems

Tags: linux, filesystems, rename, vfs

on linux filesystems, I see that [vfs_rename](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/filesystems/API-vfs-rename.html) function is used when move is called on files/directories **in the same** device/filesystem.
When move files/directories **cross file system or devices** (e.g multi device file system such as btrfs - when copy file/dir between subvolumes) I see the following vfs operations: vfs_create (on destination) and vfs_delete (on source).

Is this assumption, that vfs_rename is only called within the same file system or device is true ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, rename(2) fails with EXDEV if source and destination are across multiple file systems.